# Entity Relationship using Lists in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, development

I am creating an application using SharePoint List for storing the data. The data design would pretty much similar like if you are going to put it in a relational database, with items like many to many relationship, primary keys, foreign keys.

I would like to know what are the best practices?

Is it Possible to maintain the entity relationship data in lists ?
How can the duplication be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice? Don't do this in SharePoint. It's NOT a relational database system and you will be fighting it every step of the way. Every form, every workflow, every interaction will require code in some form, nothing will work out of the box.

Comment: how about using SPMetal?

Comment: @VarunVerma, sure, that is a possibility. But so is Access or SQL. It depends on so many factors.

Comment: Its less amount of data which is present in excel and i don't think that really need any database to store. I plan to store the data in SharePoint Lists and create relationships among them ..